# How can I use WooCommerce Bookings to schedule in-person courses?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart, use-case, woocommerce-bookings

I am trying to use WooCommerce Bookings to allow customers to choose one of two products (in-person courses) and then select a specific course date from a drop-down list. I am able to create the product but I am unsure how to add multiple course dates for that product.

To throw in a twist, I would also like the ability to increase the price if the course date is within two weeks from today.

Thank you, and any help or other solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you add your code, please. So we can see what you've done so far. If you have errors, please add them, too. Thanks

Comment: I don't really have code. I've been trying to set this up through a WooCommerce Booking product